# How to select a list from a range in database

Tags: mysql

Example:
I have a table in the database that has

```
id, startPhoneNumber, endPhoneNumber
1,  5000000               , 5000002
```

I want to change it to this in a new table (views)

```
id, PhoneNumber
1, 5000000
1, 5000001
1, 5000002
```

Comment: you have to make script and insert into new table

Comment: where you get the phone number **5000001** ? Do you calculate it or what?

Comment: from 5000000 to 5000002 is 5000000,5000001,5000002

Comment: It's possible `with` a recursive Query, but MySQL doesn't support them. Without them, the only option is a Stock procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

made a nice twist to it. You will need a counter table called counter containing integer from 0 to the maximum range you will have. Example:

```
id
0
1
2
3
```

and then make this query:

```
select t.id, (t.startPhoneNumber + counter.id) from t join counter where (t.startPhoneNumber + counter.id) <= t.endPhoneNumber
```